# Multiple Boot Manager

Tags: boot, partitioning, multi-boot, grub, boot-manager

My computer dual boots with Windows 8 and Ubuntu on separate partitions.

I am planning to install Mac OS X on another partition, but I need a better way to manage the boot options if I add more boot options in the future.

Is there a boot manager similar to the Grub manager which comes with Ubuntu, which manages all boot partitions?

The boot manager should boot into a (preferably) GUI where I can click on a partition and boot from it. (A system without mouse control such as keyboard control would be sufficient, though.)

Comment: "Better" in what way? Both GRUB and Windows Boot Manager (and their derivatives) can boot from any partition, show a boot menu, etc. What features do you find lacking?

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://sourceforge.net/projects/gujin/
It's getting a 5-star rating and supports mouse input to select the OS / kernel you want to load.